# Gradle NativeLibrarySpec producing nothing for me

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm working with gradle to build a c project. This gcc command works just fine to build my shared library:

```
gcc -shared -Iheaders/core_engine.h -lSDL2 -o ce src/c/core_engine.c
```

Here's an image of my source tree
[image]

how I have a build.gradle file that looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'c'

model {
    components {
        core_engine(NativeLibrarySpec) {
        binaries.all {
             linker.args "-lSDL2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I run gradle build core_engineSharedLibrary i get an empty folder but the build claims it was ran successfully.

Manually compiling with gcc creates the shared library, what am I doing incorrectly with gradle?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Sterling on the gradle discussion forum. I had my project file structure setup incorrectly.

The proper way is

```
src/core_engine/c/core_engine.c
```

after making that change everything built correctly.